# Shift children and subtrees horizontally in forest

Tags: margins, forest, trees, alignment, white-space

I am trying to draw a tree diagram with `forest` package. In order to have the diagram fitting within the page margins, I moved down the subtree of *NastranBulkData object*, as you can see from the image. However, there is still quite a big white space left between *NastranCaseControl object* and *NastranBulkData object* that prevents the diagram from fitting into the page margins.

[image]

How can I remove such white space so that both *NastranBulkData object* and *NastranSubcaseResult object* are shifted left? Ideally they should be shifted in such a way that the space between *Objects related to other Nastran case control entries* and the line departing from *NastranBulkData object* is equal to the separation between children in the tree (but I do not care too much about this).

MWE:

```
% Class
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Set paper geometry
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

% Forest package
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={              % style of tree nodes
                draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                align = center,
                inner sep = 2mm,
                anchor=north,
                %                     styles of tree
                forked edge,             
                l sep = 6mm,    
                fork sep = 3mm,     
            }
            [\texttt{NastranAnalysis}\\object
            [\texttt{NastranExecutiveControl}\\object
            [Solution\\sequence \#]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranCaseControl}\\object
            [\texttt{NastranSubcase}\\object array]
            [Objects related to\\other \textsc{Nastran}\\case control entries]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranBulkData}\\object
            [\texttt{Grid}\\object array, fork sep=3cm, l*=5, name=grid]
            [Objects related to other \\\textsc{Nastran} bulk data cards, fork sep=3cm, l*=5]
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object array, fork sep=3cm, l*=5
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 1]
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 2]
            [\dots]
            ]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranSubcaseResult}\\object array]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% Set paper geometry
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
% Forest package
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={              % style of tree nodes
                draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                font=\small,        % <--- 
                align = center,
                inner sep = 2mm,
                anchor=north,
                %                     styles of tree
                forked edge,
                s sep = 2mm,
                l sep = 6mm,
                fork sep = 3mm,
            }
[\texttt{NastranAnalysis}\\object
    [\texttt{NastranExecutiveControl}\\object
        [Solution\\sequence \#]
    ]
    [\texttt{NastranCaseControl}\\object
        [\texttt{NastranSubcase}\\object array]
        [Objects related to\\other \textsc{Nastran}\\case control entries]
    ]
    [\texttt{NastranBulkData}\\object
        [, l*=4,coordinate
            [\texttt{Grid}\\object array]
            [Objects related to other \\\textsc{Nastran} bulk data cards]
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object array,
                [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 1]
                [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 2]
                [\dots]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [\texttt{NastranSubcaseResult}\\object array]
]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In code is added additional level with node as `coordinate`. Also is reduced font size to `\small`. One option is also to reduce `inner sep` to 1mm and use normal font size.

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Comment: *Grid object array* is at the same level of *Objects related to other Nastran bulk data cards*. Apart from this, your solution works perfectly adding `l*=4` after `coordinate`.

Comment: huh, I insert `coordinate on the wrong level :-(. Corrected now.

Comment: This does not seem to reproduce the OP's tree. For instance, in your tree, the `Grid` node has two children while in the OP's version it has none.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, you are right. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

A reliable way of shifting nodes in a forest is to use the `before computing xy` key. (I also added `calign child=2` to avoid the kink.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% Set paper geometry
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}

% Forest package
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={              % style of tree nodes
                draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                align = center,
                inner sep = 2mm,
                anchor=north,
                %                     styles of tree
                forked edge,             
                l sep = 6mm,    
                fork sep = 3mm,s sep=0.35em
            }
            [\texttt{NastranAnalysis}\\object
            [\texttt{NastranExecutiveControl}\\object
            [Solution\\sequence \#]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranCaseControl}\\object
            [\texttt{NastranSubcase}\\object array]
            [Objects related to\\other \textsc{Nastran}\\case control entries]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranBulkData}\\object,before computing
            xy={s+=-9em},calign child=2     
            [\texttt{Grid}\\object array, fork sep=3cm, l*=5, name=grid]
            [Objects related to other \\\textsc{Nastran} bulk data cards, fork sep=3cm, l*=5]
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object array, fork sep=3cm, l*=5
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 1]
            [\texttt{NastranPart}\\object 2]
            [\dots]
            ]
            ]
            [\texttt{NastranSubcaseResult}\\object array,
            before computing xy={s+=-9em}]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `showframe` option is used to show that the resulting tree really fits on the page, of course you want to drop it in your document.